# Pixel values change when opening in other version

Tags: qgis

I have a raster layer with pixel values ranging from 0-0.346, which is a result after calculations in QGIS raster calculator (QGIS version 2.18.26). I want to open the same layer in QGIS 3 on another computer to continue my work there. However, when I open in in QGIS 3, suddenly the values ranges from 0-0.404. This is after having compressed the raster together with others to which the same thing happened), uploaded them to my drive, downloaded them and unzipped them on the computer with QGIS 3. Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Comment: what type of compression did you use ? Do you reproduce the problem with the uncompressed raster ?

Comment: Yes, it seems like the issue is not the compression process.

Comment: and how do you compute the range ? With large images, statistics are built based on a sample of the pixels, but different stats don't mean that you data actually changed

Comment: In addition to more, I've been calculating shares of raster layers of 30s resolution and multiplying them with each other. The change seem to happen in the process of switching from 2.18 to 3... In all layers, the range seem to become broader; with a lower minimum value and a higher maximum value.

Comment: As radouxju states, in version 2.18 min max values are calculated by default as a cumulative count from 2-98% of the data. In version 3.xx values are related to the actual min/max values. In that sense it coul be possible that you are facing this. Try calculating in 2.18 the actual min/max values and see if they are the same as in version 3. Another thing you can check in the layer properties/metadata the actual statistics of the layer

Comment: You are correct, that was actually the case - many thanks for the help both of you.